# SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] Uncaught SystemException returned to top level from NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

When trying to solve 8 equations in 8 unknowns, I get `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or is this something that should not really happen.  Here is the code:

```
f={w1 + w2 + w3 + w4 == 2, w1*x1 + w2*x2 + w3*x3 + w4*x4 == 0, 
 w1*x1^2 + w2*x2^2 + w3*x3^2 + w4*x4^2 == 2/3, 
 w1*x1^3 + w2*x2^3 + w3*x3^3 + w4*x4^3 == 0, 
 w1*x1^4 + w2*x2^4 + w3*x3^4 + w4*x4^4 == 2/5, 
 w1*x1^5 + w2*x2^5 + w3*x3^5 + w4*x4^5 == 0, 
 w1*x1^6 + w2*x2^6 + w3*x3^6 + w4*x4^6 == 2/7, 
 w1*x1^7 + w2*x2^7 + w3*x3^7 + w4*x4^7 == 0};

NSolve[f, {w1, w2, w3, w4, x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is using *Mathematica* 10.4, on Windows 7, 16 GB RAM, 64 bits.

This happens only with `NSolve`. Using `Solve` does not generate this error, which is even more strange.

**question is**: Should this error be generated? Is this a user error, or a problem in `NSolve`?

Comment: You are aware there are [nicer ways to generate Gaussian quadrature rules](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34047), right?

Comment: @J.M. thanks for the link. No, I did not know about those other methods.

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug, for a possible workaround switch to a non-default method, for example

```
 f = {w1 + w2 + w3 + w4 == 2, w1*x1 + w2*x2 + w3*x3 + w4*x4 == 0, 
 w1*x1^2 + w2*x2^2 + w3*x3^2 + w4*x4^2 == 2/3, 
 w1*x1^3 + w2*x2^3 + w3*x3^3 + w4*x4^3 == 0, 
 w1*x1^4 + w2*x2^4 + w3*x3^4 + w4*x4^4 == 2/5, 
 w1*x1^5 + w2*x2^5 + w3*x3^5 + w4*x4^5 == 0, 
 w1*x1^6 + w2*x2^6 + w3*x3^6 + w4*x4^6 == 2/7, 
 w1*x1^7 + w2*x2^7 + w3*x3^7 + w4*x4^7 == 0};

NSolve[f, {w1, w2, w3, w4, x1, x2, x3, x4}, Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"]
```