# Any possible to save a 'partial' result of NDSolve when it was aborted due to insufficient memory?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, save

I have run a `NDSolve` code for an extremely long time. Unfortunately, it was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation. At the same time, MMA give the hint:

> > Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[[Ellipsis], _SystemException]. >>

with the output

> SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

My question is that is there any workaround for saving or check the existing result of integration? Just want to have a look the result just before the break down. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Lack of detail will certainly hinder us from assisting you. Are you solving an ODE or a PDE, for starters?

Comment: The answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38081/1063) may meet your need.

Comment: And, the answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111684/1063) suggests that you may have encountered a bug.  If so, to obtain a possible workaround, please provide the simplest `NDSolve` example you have that exhibits this behavior.